# Size autoplot (ggfortify) does not work

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggfortify

I am trying to adjust the `size` of the line in the autoplot, for a simple graph it works, but for two lines it does not work, any idea of how to solve it.

```
library(ggfortify);library(forecast)
autoplot(AirPassengers, ts.colour = "blue", size = 2) + theme_light()
d.arima <- auto.arima(AirPassengers)
d.forecast <- forecast(d.arima, level = 10, h = 50)
autoplot(cbind(Ajustado = fitted(d.arima),Original = AirPassengers), size = 2) + labs(y = "") + theme_light()
```

The second line of code works `size`, but in the last one it does not

Answer (score 3):

The argument `size` works in `ggfortify:::autplot.ts`:

```
ggfortify:::autoplot.ts(cbind(Ajustado = fitted(d.arima),
                              Original = AirPassengers), size = 2, facets=F) + 
labs(y = "") + theme_light()
```

[image]